# How to find the re-occurence of the string in array stored in the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe consisting string values in an array of strings something like below.

```
date files
13/7 '['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt']'
14/7 '['b.txt','d.txt']'
15/7 '['e.txt','f.txt']'
16/7 '['a.txt','g.txt']'
17/7 '['c.txt','h.txt']'
```

So 'a.txt' is present in 16/7 line, similar for 'b.txt'(17/7) and 'c.txt'(17/7). I want to find for all the values present in the string.

What I tried is to find iterate through all the rows for each values but that is very time consuming. So is there any quicker way to do it.

EDIT:
Desired output is total difference between the re-occurrence. 
So in that case difference is 3 days for a.txt,1 day for b.txt and 4 days for c.txt. Output should be [3,1,4]/8 anything will do.

```
date files                        difference
13/7 ['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt']    [3,1,4] or 8
....
```

Comment: How is your desired output?

Comment: For now I just wanted to check the re-occurrence but in future I will need difference between the date. So for 'a.txt' it would be 3 days, 'b.txt' it is 1 and 'c.txt' it is 4.

Comment: How many different files are there ? Do you have the name of the files ('a.txt' ... etc) stored somewhere ?

Comment: @OzeriossSmith these file names are stored in the log filles

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on the re-occurence stuff and hadn't work on this edit. Hope that helps.

**Initialisation :**

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
  'date': ["13/7", "14/7", "15/7", "16/7", "17/7"], 
  'files': [
    '[\'a.txt\',\'b.txt\',\'c.txt\']',
    '[\'b.txt\',\'d.txt\']',
    '[\'e.txt\',\'f.txt\']',
    '[\'a.txt\',\'g.txt\']',
    '[\'c.txt\',\'h.txt\']'
  ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

**Dates :**

It will probably useful if you want the difference of days between two occurences.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m')
```

**Files :**

Determine every files you got in the second columns :

```
import re
rg = r'\w*.txt'
df['separated_files']=df['files'].apply(lambda x:re.findall(rg,x))
allFiles = [item for sublist in df['separated_files'].values.tolist() for item in sublist]
allDistinctFiles = list(set(allFiles))
```

Add column of occurences for each files:

```
for file in allDistinctFiles:
  df[file] = df['separated_files'].apply(lambda x : 1 if any((i for i in x if i.find(file) >= 0)) else 0)
```

For now, I have nothing better. I'll maybe think about it later.

Comment: Thank you, it works to check if the file is present or not. I'll see if I can get the difference between two occurrences but there are large number of unique files and dataframe will go bigger and that case if we add columns for every file. Though I don't know if it will create and problem or not

Comment: Yes, not amazing answer I know. 
I think if the size stays reasonable it will work fine.
I almost got a solution with the df.diff() function, but there was a bug and hadn't enough time to spend, maybe tonight.

Comment: yeah, I tried with 4000 unique files, it took sometime though not much but I couldn't find any solution to calculate the difference between two occurrences. Let me know if you find any. 
Thanks.